# Bitbucket CI/CD pipeline - Deploy to AWS with Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, bitbucket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to deploy web api on aws elastic beanstalk using bitbucker CI/CD pipeline. Below is the configuration for the same.

```
image: microsoft/dotnet:sdk

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - dotnetcore
        deployment: myapi-test1
        script: # Modify the comma`nds below to build your repository.
          - pipe: atlassian/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy:0.5.4
            variables:
              AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: '<access_key>'
              AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: '<secret_key>'
              AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: 'us-east-1'
              APPLICATION_NAME: 'myapi'
              ENVIRONMENT_NAME: 'test'
              ZIP_FILE: 'https://applicationxyz.s3.amazonaws.com/applicationxyz.zip'
              S3_BUCKET: 'myapplication' # Optional.
              # VERSION_LABEL: '<string>' # Optional.
              # DESCRIPTION: '<string>' # Optional.
              # WAIT: '<boolean>' # Optional.
              # WAIT_INTERVAL: '<integer>' # Optional.
              # COMMAND: '<string>' # Optional.
              # DEBUG: '<boolean>' # Optional.
```

However, I am getting below error for the zip file.

> INFO: The application source bundle doesn't have a known file
>   extension (zip, jar or war). This might cause some issues.  INFO:
>   Uploading to s3 bucket: myapplication.  The user-provided path
>   https://applicationxyz.s3.amazonaws.com/applicationxyz.zip does not
>   exist.

I am not sure why I am getting this error. Prior to this we are already deploying the web api manually on elastic beanstalk, so there are few zip files already available. So, I have even tried to use those, still the issue is not resolved.

Any help on this appreciated !

**EDIT 1:** Updated bitbucket-pipelines.yml files

```
image: atlassian/default-image:2

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: "Build and Test"
        script:
          - echo "Everything is awesome!"
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get install -y zip
          - zip -j application.zip MyApplication.WebAPI/*
          - pipe: atlassian/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy:0.2.3
            variables:
              AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
              AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
              AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
              APPLICATION_NAME: $APPLICATION_NAME
              COMMAND: 'upload-only'
              ZIP_FILE: 'application.zip'
              S3_BUCKET: 'bitbucketcicd'
              VERSION_LABEL: 'deployApi-$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER-multiple'
    - step:
        name: "Deploy to Test"
        deployment: test
        script:
        - echo "Deployment!"
        - pipe: atlassian/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy:0.2.3
          variables:
            AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
            AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
            AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
            APPLICATION_NAME: $APPLICATION_NAME
            COMMAND: 'deploy-only'
            VERSION_LABEL: 'deployApi-$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER-multiple'
            ENVIRONMENT_NAME: $ENVIRONMENT_NAME
            WAIT: 'true'
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to define artifats in the first step and pass them to next step.

```
image: atlassian/default-image:2

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: "Build and Test"
        script:
          - echo "Everything is awesome!"
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get install -y zip
          - zip -j application.zip MyApplication.WebAPI/*
          - pipe: atlassian/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy:0.2.3
            variables:
              AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
              AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
              AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
              APPLICATION_NAME: $APPLICATION_NAME
              COMMAND: 'upload-only'
              ZIP_FILE: 'application.zip'
              S3_BUCKET: 'bitbucketcicd'
              VERSION_LABEL: 'deployApi-$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER-multiple'
 # Define an artifact to pass the zip file to the next step
        artifacts: 
          - application.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

The ZIP_FILE parameter is used to specify the local archive with your source code. You shouldn't pass the URL of an object in S3. Here is an example (more examples are available on in the [README](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy/src/master/):

```
  - pipe: atlassian/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy:0.5.4
    variables:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
      AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: 'us-east-1'
      APPLICATION_NAME: 'my-app-name'
      ENVIRONMENT_NAME: 'production'
      ZIP_FILE: 'application.zip'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have updated the bitbucket-pipelines.yml configuration under EDIT 1, now at least elastic beanstalk is trying to deploy the application. However, the publish files,dlls are not available in the S3 bucket which is failing the application. So, any idea how can i get that ?

Comment: So when does your pipeline fail exactly? Does it fail when you call the "upload-only" or "deploy-only?

Comment: It doesn't give any error, but when I check the S3 bucket for publish code files, these are not available. After this when I run the application it gives error as no publish are found...

Comment: Any suggestions on this?